# Why can't I see the special world types in Minecraft even though I am pressing shift?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to try to play special kind of worlds (like `Floating Island` and `Debug`), and I remember that in order to do that, you need to press <kbd>shift</kbd> while clicking on the `World Type` button on the `Create New World` screen; however, for some reason, when I tried this, it wouldn't work. Can someone please tell me what I was doing wrong?

I tried googling "***can you still generate different world types in minecraft java edition 2023***", but couldn't find helpful results.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of what you do see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong key! Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Floating Islands and Caves were [removed in 1.18](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Old_Buffet_world_generators) due to their consistently buggy nature, but can be accessed in older versions with the **Buffet**/**Single Biome** world type.

Comment: Thank you! Just one thing: when I tried this, I only got the debug world (FYI: It was very cool!). Are there other ones, or is that the only one there currently is (right now)?

Comment: @TimMcCool Only Debug is added as a separate world type. For Floating Islands you'll need to go back to 1.17 or older.

Answer (score -2):

That is a wrong key, you need to hold ALT, not SHIFT.

And also, floating islands world gen doesn't exist anymore, there is only the DEBUG world.

Comment: What information does this convey that is not covered by Corsaka's answer?